# Ito representation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

What is the way to find a function $f$ such that for a stochastic process, for example $e^{B_T}$ we can write:
$$ e^{B_T} = E[e^{B_T}] + \int_{0}^{T}f(t)dB_t$$?

Comment: Can we have more information on the function $f$ ? Any regularity conditions ? Is it deterministic ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ito's formula: for a $C^2$ function $f$,

\begin{align*}
f(B_t) = f(0) + \int_0^t f'(B_s)dB_s + \frac 12 \int_0^t f''(B_s)ds
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with: $$ e^{B_T} = 1 + \int_{0}^{T} e^{B_t} dB_t + 1/2 \int_{0}^{T} e^{B_t} dt$$ How should I continue?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I misunderstood your question.  For this, you would want to find a function $f$ such that $f(t)e^{B_t}$ is a martingale and $f(T)=1$.  Applying Ito's formula to $f(T)e^{B_T}$ will give you a differential equation to solve to find $f$ so that all of the non-stochastic integrals cancel out and give the result you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please tell me on which book and page of it, I can learn about this? Because I can’t understand why $f(t)e^{B_t}$ should be a martingale and why $f(T) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying Ito formula to the function $\phi : x \mapsto e^{x} $ and using the process $B$. We have :
\begin{equation}
e^{B_T} = 1 + \frac12\int_0^Te^{B_t}dt+ \int_0^Te^{B_t}dB_t
\end{equation}
Now taking the expectation on both sides, we have that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{B_T}] = \left(1 + \frac12\int_0^Te^{B_t}dt\right) + 0
\end{equation}
Note that by definition of the stochastic integral, we have $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^Te^{B_t}dB_t\right]=0$. This follows from the fact that the function $f : (t,\omega) \mapsto \exp(B(t,\omega))$ belong to $H^2[0,T]$ where $H^2$ is the space of progressively measurable function such that :
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\int_0^T f^2(t,\omega)dt < \infty
\end{equation}
Therefore by identification, we have:
$e^{B_T} = \mathbb{E}[e^{B_T}] + \int_0^Tf(t)dB_t$